# How to prevent UI thread locking in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, ui-thread

Within a view I have a button that makes a call to a method within my view model

search.xaml

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtSearchField"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Style="{StaticResource SearchTxtBoxStyle}"
             Text="{Binding SearchTerm, Mode=TwoWay}"
             KeyDown="txtSearchField_KeyDown"
             ToolTipService.ToolTip="{StaticResource TTsearchField}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:KeyTrigger Key="Enter">
                <ei:CallMethodAction
                    TargetObject="{Binding}"
                    MethodName="GetSearchResult"/>
            </ei:KeyTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <StackPanel x:Name="searchButtons"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="3,2,5,2"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="SearchButton"
                Margin="13,1,9,-1"
                ap:AttachedProperties.TabIndex="2"
                Content="{StaticResource btnSearch}"
                Style="{StaticResource blackButton}"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{StaticResource TTSavebtn}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction
                    TargetObject="{Binding}"
                    MethodName="GetSearchResult"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

I also have within the view an IsBusy Indicator

```
 <Grid>
        <!-- Bind IsBusy to IsBusy -->
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator Name="isBusyIndicator" 
            IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
    </Grid>
```

(I am using SimpleMVVM toolkit with this project)

Within the view model I have my method declared as well as the properties for an IsBusyIndicator etc.

searchviewmodel.xaml

```
 public void GetSearchResult()
    {
        //query

       // IsBusy = true;  //Originally set the IsBusyFlag here to see if it would fire 

            SearchResults = this._DataModel.GetSearchResults(this.SearchTerm);
            this.SearchHistory = this._DataModel.AddSearchHistoryItem(this.SearchTerm);   
    }


private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsBusy);
        }
    }
```

Then within the model I have my async call to the WCF service

```
public ObservableCollection<QueryResponse> GetSearchResults(string searchQuery)
    { 
        SearchClient sc = new SearchClient();
        sc.QueryCompleted +=new EventHandler<QueryCompletedEventArgs>(sc_QueryCompleted);
        sc.QueryAsync(new Query { QueryText = searchQuery });
        return this.SearchResults;      
    }  

    void sc_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SearchResults != null)
            {
                this.SearchResults.Clear();
                this.SearchResults.Add(e.Result);

            }
            else
            {
                this.SearchResults.Add(e.Result);

            }
           // IsBusy = false;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The search control loads the results through a listbox control that has a dataTempalte selector class applied.

The issue I am seeing is since this call is being invoked from the UI the UI thread is locking up until the datatemplates are selected for the collection and the results returned. To this point the IsBusy indicator is not even firing.

My question is can someone point me in the direction on how these calls should be made so that the UI thread is not locked? Should I be looking for some sort of background thread etc to make the call so that the UI thread can invoke the IsBusy indicator etc.

Please let me know if you need more detail or additional samples.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is your locking the UI thread, While on the surface it appears that everything should work correctly given how things are structured, without the code thats in SearchResult in your model, I can't say for sure where you issue might be.

Also, you have a null reference issue in *sc_QueryCompleted*, your check if SearchResults is not equal to null, but in your else condition you attempt to add a value to the object you've just verified will be null. The corrected version is below:

```
if (SearchResults != null) {
    this.SearchResults.Clear();
    this.SearchResults.Add(e.Result);
} else {
    //I'm guessing at the type from your code
    this.SearchResults = new List<SearchResult)();
    this.SearchResults.Add(e.Result);
}
```